# Verb Past Tense Help

Tags: tense, verbs

As the storm approached, the sky becomes dark and the wind increased.

Should it be becomes or became?

Comment: Did you try a dictionary? What did you find?

Answer (score -1):

It should be "became", the past tense of to become.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer but I suspect that the person who did expected you to explain why so that the questioner could understand the reason for your answer.